# focus isnt working for text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, setfocus

Source ->

```
<input name="ctl00$MainContent$MapUserControl$6551_Edit_artintheparkssculpturelocations_32_id" type="text" maxlength="50" id="ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_6551_Edit_artintheparkssculpturelocations_32_id" onchange="MaxLength(50, this, 'id')" class="control-label form-control" id2="6551_Edit_artintheparkssculpturelocations_32_id">
```

I can update the text in the field by

```
x = document.getElementById('ctl00_MainContent_MapUserControl_6551_Edit_artintheparkssculpturelocations_32_id')
x.value ="bla";
```

However I can't update the focus...

```
x.focus();
```

returns undefined as expected but nothing happens the text field.
I have also tried autofocus, and grabbin the element with Jquery instead of JS....
Still no joy...any idea why?

Comment: Its working fine check here: https://jsfiddle.net/nsne8tcq/

Comment: have you used that id twice?

Comment: id and id2 @Orangesandlemons

Comment: @MayankPandeyz working in fiddle yes but not in my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have faced similar issue. Calling focus through setTimeOut is what you need.

```
setTimeout(function() { x.focus()}, 1);
```

Comment: @John the return value is incase you want to kill the timeout function with `clearTimeout()`

Comment: oh right ok...so it is returning? just not working on screen, Must be something else affecting it

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to trigger that event by using following code

```
x.trigger('focus');
```